# Using Telerik MVC extensions, Grid control, why vertical and/or horizontal scroll is not appearing when resizing a window?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

Hy,

In my app I use Telerik extensions for MVC Grid control:

[Telerik Grid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid)

Does anyone have any idea why when I resize the window (in any browser) the vertical or horizontal scroll is not appearing?

I am setting the width and height of the grid to 100%.

```
 @(Html.Telerik().Grid<MyViewModel>()
      .Name("MyGrid")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "display:table; width:100%; height: 100%;" })
...)
```

I've tried even putting the grid into a div with width and height 100%... still no scroll when I resize the window.

Thanks in advance,

Jeff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fond the solution. Somehow the style of the page had 'overflow:hidden'; after setting to 'auto', all the scrolls are there.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for scrollbars on the whole window, or just the Grid?

I got scrollbars on the Grid, when I added a `div` around the grid, set the height to 100px, and set overflow to auto:

```
<div style="height: 100px; overflow:auto;">
    @(Html.Telerik().Grid<MyViewModel>()
      .Name("MyGrid")
    ...)
</div>
```

It doesn't sound like a problem with the grid, but with your HTML.  Add some more code and more detail on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm looking for the scrollbars on the whole window

Answer (score 0):

For Vertical Scroll we can use the following and for horizontal scroll just use  a div

```
<div class="DataGridXScroll">

@(Html.Telerik().Grid(listCustomerStatus)
                .Name("grvSalesAdjustment")
                .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(k => k.CustCode))
                .Columns(column =>
                {

                })
               .Selectable()
               .Pageable(page => page.PageSize(100))
               .Scrollable(scroll => scroll.Height(300))
)
 </div>
```

add the following ***CSS***

```
.DataGridXScroll
{
    width: 1000px;   
    overflow-x: scroll;
    text-align:left;
}
```

This is work in Firefox and other browser. For ***IE*** just use the following ***CSS***

```
.t-grid
{
   position: static;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.t-grid-content
{
   overflow-x: hidden;
   position:static; 
   width:100%;  
}

.t-grid-header-wrap
{
   position:static;    
}

.t-grid-content
{
   overflow-x: hidden;    
}

.t-grid-footer-wrap
{
  position:static;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set specific width that would trigger the scrollbar.
Sample;

.Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(430))

Hope it helps!